# Possible Oracle Bug with "greater than 0" in where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a select statement which delivers the wrong number of rows.
I can reproduce the problem on `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production` and on `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production` I can not reproduce it on `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production`

Testdata:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON AS
SELECT LEVEL AS ID, 'Person_'||LEVEL AS NAME, 10 as maxVal
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

create table orders as
SELECT LEVEL AS ID, 'Order_'||LEVEL AS NAME
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

If i try the following Query, i get only 3 Results instead of 5:

```
select p.*
      from person p
     where (maxVal - (select count(*)
                         from orders o
                        where o.id = p.id)
           )  > 0
```

If i modify the Query to the following, i get 5 Results (which should be the correct Number):

```
select p.*
      from person p
     where (maxVal - (select count(*)
                         from orders o
                        where o.id = p.id)
           )  > 1
```

Also the following modification delivers the correct Result:

```
select p.*
      from person p
     where (maxVal - (select count(*)
                         from orders o
                        where o.id = p.id)
           )  > 0 + 0
```

I also get the correct number of Results if i use Bind Variables:

```
select p.*
      from person p
     where (maxVal - (select count(*)
                         from orders o
                        where o.id = p.id)
           )  > :num
```

So, is there any (known) Bug if i use "greater than 0"?

Comment: *"I also get the correct number of Results if i use Bind Variables"* - What value did you put in the variable?

Comment: I can use 0 or 1 as Bind-Value. So it seems to be only a Problem if i use "> 0" hardcoded.

Comment: Weird issue indeed. The count should be either 0 or 1, so the calculated value should be 10 or 9. In either case you should get all persons. Unclear to my why this doesn't work, but I can reproduce it.

Comment: If you put the calculation in the fields, you will see a nice 10 or 9 returned for each person.. Also, it works if you pull maxval into the count query: `(select p.maxVal - count(*) from ....) > 0`, but that's merely a work-around not an explanation.

Comment: Yes, there are some Modifications which act as a Workaround, e.g.: `select nvl(count(*), 0)`

Comment: Which suggests that the `count` function returns `null` rather than `0`. I don't easily call something a bug, but this seriously looks like one.

Comment: Possibly bug 18066615? You should probably raise a service request anyway...

Comment: I'm getting the correct number of results in Sqlfiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84d00/1/0

Comment: @Nitish - SQL Fiddle is 11.2.0.2; I think it's established in the question that this doesn't happen before 11.2.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that came after another bug was patched.

> ("Bug 17564992  Wrong results with fix for bug 12999577 present My
>   Oracle Support Doc ID 17564992.8")

It has it's own patch (Patch 17564992, we haven't tested) but there is a workaround (that we tested):

```
alter session set "_fix_control" = '12999577:0';
alter session set "_optimizer_squ_bottomup"= FALSE;
```